# The getter 'documents' was called on null Flutter issue on StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Even the application loads and works I get this kind of error:

```
The getter 'documents' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: documents
```

this is the code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('shippingAddress').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data please Wait');
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 1000,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data.documents[index]['alias'],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making changes like below also make sure in your case 'shippingAddress' node spelling is correct comparing with firebase.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('shippingAddress').snapshots(),
          builder: (ctx, Snapshot) {
            if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
    
            final shippingAddressDocs = Snapshot.data.documents;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: shippingAddressDocs.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Text(
                      shippingAddressDocs [index]['alias'],
                    ));
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

i have not tested the code but it should work